# How to add multiple new/create routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a client controller and views which already functions for all the default actions.  How do I add a `new_account` and `create_account` actions that also work with routing?

The idea is... there are new clients, but some `clients` can also function as an account that logs into the website.  I want to prompt for different fields based on whether a client is being created or a login account is being created.  I don't want two separate models with duplicate information.

client_controller.rb - index, new, create, edit, update, destroy, new_account, create_account

client views - I have views for each of the actions within the controller.

Routing - ../new_account should display the `new_account` view for the client model, not the `new` view.

Hopefully this makes sense.  I'm guessing this isn't difficult but I'm just missing how.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
match 'new_account', 'client#new_account', :via => :get
match 'create_account', 'client#create_account', :via => :post
```

View all your routes by running `rake routes`.

Refer to more info on routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the lead.  The correct syntax was:      `match 'new_account' => 'users#new_account', :via => :get`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :clients do
  new do
    scope type: 'account' do
      get :account, to: 'clients#new'
      post :account, to: 'clients#create'
    end
  end
end
```

and the actions you need will be accessible at `GET|POST /clients/new/account`.
In the controller you'll have `params[:type]` to indicate this specific case.